# How to keep specific fields in InnerClass using Proguard

Tags: java, proguard

I have a java class, which has some public methods, which I want to keep. (This is done already)
I also have an InnerClass which contains static constants.
The class has following structure.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static MyInnerClass {
        public static final String MY_CONSTANT_1="constant 1";
        public static final String MY_CONSTANT_2="constant 2";
        public static final String MY_CONSTANT_3="constant 3";
        public static final String MY_CONSTANT_4="constant 4";
        public static final int MY_INT_1 = 1;
        public static final int MY_INT_2 = 2;
    }

    public void method1() {    }
    public void method2() {    }
    public void method3() {    }
    public void method4() {    }
}
```

I want to proguard the above class. I want to keep some part and remove the remaining.
I want to keep the methods `method1` & `method2`. I want to keep the inner class `MyInnerClass`. I want to keep some fields of `MyInnerClass` like `MY_CONSTANT_1`, `MY_CONSTANT_2` & `MY_INT_1`. Rest all should be removed.

My proguard is as below --

```
-keep public class com.mypackage.MyClass**
-keepclassmembers class com.mypackage.MyClass** {
    public *** method1(...);
    public *** method2(...);
 }

-keepclassmembers class com.mypackage.MyClass.MyInnerClass** {
    public static final java.lang.String MY_CONSTANT_1;
    public static final java.lang.String MY_CONSTANT_2;
    public static final int MY_INT_1;
}
```

This applies correctly on top class, but my MyInnerClass is empty
I searched but most of them tell either to remove it completely or keep all.

If you guys need more info, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use '$' as delimiter between a class and its inner class, then the rule should work correctly:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.mypackage.MyClass$MyInnerClass {
    public static <fields>;
}
```